# Vite+Vue - Package referenced via npm link can't resolve vite.resolve.alias

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I'm developing a package to help other developers here in our company.

I know that I can create aliases to make the code more cleaner and help the readability of it.

So:

## PACKAGE PROJECT

### vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
    
  resolve:{
        preserveSymlinks: false,
        alias:{
            '@' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

  },
// ....
})
```

Assume that I've  the following folder structure

- src

  - helpers

    - commonHelper.js
  - index.js

### src/index.js

```js
import {merge} from '@/helpers/commonHelper.js'
export {merge}
```

## PROJECT THAT REFERENCES PACKAGE PROJECT

### vite.config.js

It alsos have a vite.config.js with an @ alias pointing to it self src

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
    
  resolve:{
        preserveSymlinks: false,
        alias:{
            '@' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

  },
// ....
})
```

## anyfile.js

Lets assume that my package project is called **foo** and it's referenced using **npm link** for testing now, after finishing the package it will be referenced using npm install

```js
import {merge} from 'foo'

merge({},{});
```

When i try to run my project i got the following error

```bash
  [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@/helpers/commonHelper.js" from 
  "..\..\npmPackages\foo\src\index.js". Does the file exist?       
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: E:/_Development/foo/src/index.js
  3  |  import {merge} from '@/helpers/commonHelper.js'
     |                       ^
  4  |  export {merge}
      at formatError (file:///E:/_Development/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-557f29e6.js:40853:46)
      at TransformContext.error (file:///E:/_Development/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-557f29e6.js:40849:19)
      at normalizeUrl (file:///E:/_Development/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-557f29e6.js:37586:33)
      at async TransformContext.transform (file:///E:/_Development/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-557f29e6.js:37719:47)
      at async Object.transform (file:///E:/_Development/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-557f29e6.js:41102:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///E:/_Development/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-557f29e6.js:37364:29)
```

As far i noticed the problem is happening because @ is pointing to  the project that references the **foo** package

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using Vite to build the lib.

In that case using "npm link" or the publishing process, you should point in your package.json of the package using the field "module" to the generated ESM library file instead of the actual source code.

Then you can use the package in your other project same as if it was installed from some package registry.

Comment: In which vite config should i put it?

Comment: And if I needed to use more aliases?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your question carefully enough. I fear what you currently want to do isn't working so well. When using "npm link" the package should be already in a "prepared" state. Meaning your paths inside of the package need to be correctly resolved as relative paths and the configured paths in your package.json of the package need to point to the bundled files.

I guess that publishing of the package and including it without npm link also doesn't work yet, right? I will however, update my post.

Comment: can you share an example of that? I don't know if I understood it currectly

Comment: Sorry, but that would take too much time. I would recommend that you first read the content of other packages that you've installed and that are placed in your node_modules. Looking at the files that are referenced inside the package.json and try to find the corresponding files that are shipped with the packages. You'll find that packages sometimes ship not nice readable code. That is, because bundlers like Vite are creating bundle code that can be used as-is by any project installing the package.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use '/src', use '@/' instead

Comment: I'm trying to do that, but I'm having problems...